# R programming: How to store the escape sequence "\store" in a variable

Tags: r, file, escaping

I would like to store the following file path in a variable.
x = "main\def\file_001"

It throughs the following error:

Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""main\d"

Comment: `x = "main\\def\\file_001"`

Comment: Take a look at `?file.path` for a safer approach.

Comment: You can use @snoram's suggestion or use forward path separators `x <- "main/dev/file_001"`.